# A Game in Probability

Tags: probability, game-theory

You and n other players ( $n \ge 1$ ) play a game. Each player chooses a real number between 0 and 1. A referee also chooses a number between 0 and 1. The player who chooses the closest number to the referee's number wins. What should be your choice. Will it depend on $n$ ?

Assume that the n players (other than yourself) and the referee choose the numbers uniformly between 0 and 1.

Can someone give a sketch of the solution? I've been trying this but unable to produce an answer.

Edit:You may ignore two or more players choosing the same number

Comment: What happens if there are ties?  For example, what happens if all the players choose $.5$?

Comment: @lulu (with prob 1) none of the others will because they are choosing uniformly on [0,1].

Comment: Oh okay. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @almagest  I don't understand.  If my choice is forced on me (or made by some impartial process) then what's the question?

Comment: @almagest  Ah, I see.  The players, other than the special player, choose by machine.  Got it.  I think the other problem is more interesting...where everyone is trying to out think everyone else.

Comment: Ran a simple simulation with Excel on 100K tries and 2 other players, always taking the same number. Not surprisingly, choosing $x=1/2$ does best with probability of winning approximately $41.6\%$ and the probability of winning increasing over $(0,1/2)$ and symmetric around $1/2$.

Comment: Moreover, winning probability numerically is fitted by a parabola with equation $p = 0.1662 + 1.0052x - 1.0105x^2$ for the guess $x$, with $R^2=1$

Comment: someone should ask the other problem, regarding finding equilibria when everyone tries to play optimally!  I am too lazy.

Comment: How are the number chosen? Do all the player chose at the same time, if so how can we ignore two players choosing the same number? If the players play one by one, what information is available to the player when choosing its number: does he know how many players played before him, what number each player picked, how many players will play after him? This is important as it can strongly impact one's strategy. If I know that one player picked 0.5 and another picked 0.51, I can pick 0.49, unless there is more player to play: 0.25 would then become a better move.

Comment: @AllirionX The assumption was that the referee and all other players except you choose, independently, a random number with uniform distribution in $[0,1]$ .  You are free to choose any number in $[0,1]$, but you do not know any of the other choices.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I like your answer, but I felt like the problem would be better answered by game theory (and information are missing to solve such problem such) : but you made me realise that the other "players" are not actual players - they pick a random number without trying to win.

Comment: @AllirionX Yes! The first thing that struck my mind after reading the problem was game theory. Can you provide a solution?

Comment: @SiddharthAcharya I'd like to try, but, as is, we lack information: can the other players have a strategy or do they pick random numbers, what do each player knows about the game (number of players, numbed picked by the other players, ...), how are the numbers picked (simultaneously or not), how can we ignore two players choosing the same number, how many times is the game played, can the player chat during/between each play, etc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let the referee's number be $Y$, and your choice $X$. Then you win if nobody's choice is in the interval from $X$ to $2Y-X$.  If $0 \le 2Y-X \le 1$, that interval has length $2|Y-X|$.
But if $2Y-X < 0$, its intersection with $[0,1]$ has length $X$, and if $2Y-X > 1$ it has length $1-X$.  The probability that none of the other players make a choice in an interval of length $L$ contained in $[0,1]$ is $(1-L)^n$. Thus the conditional probability that you win, given $X=x$ and $Y=y$, is
$$ \cases{(1-2|y-x|)^n & if $x/2 \le y \le (1+x)/2$\cr
           (1-x)^n & if $y \le x/2$\cr
           x^n & if $y \ge (1+x)/2$\cr}$$
Integrating over $y$, I find that the probability that you win if you choose $x$ is
$$ f(x) = {\frac { \left( x\,n+2\,x-1 \right)  \left( 1-x \right) ^{n}+ \left( -
n-2 \right) {x}^{n+1}+2+ \left( n+1 \right) {x}^{n}}{2\,n+2}}
$$
An optimal strategy would be to choose $x$ that maximizes this.

One critical point is $x=1/2$, but $f''(1/2) = (n-4) n 2^{1-n}$, so if $n > 4$ this is a local minimum.  For example, if $n=5$ we have 
$$f(x) = {\frac { \left( 7\,x-1 \right)  \left( 1-x \right) ^{5}}{12}}-{\frac {7\,{x}^{6}}{12}}+{\frac{1}{6}}+{\frac {{x}^{5}}{2}}$$
whose maximum on $[0,1]$ is at the real roots of $7\,{x}^{4}-14\,{x}^{3}+18\,{x}^{2}-11\,x+2$, approximately  $0.2995972362$ and  $0.7004027638$.

On the other hand, for $n \le 4$ the optimal solution is $x = 1/2$.

Comment: +1 This is a wonderful answer, but is there a way to see some (small) part of this _without_ calculus?  E.g. why $x=1/2$ is not optimal for $n>4$ or perhaps for "large enough" $n$?

Comment: Blows my mind that 1/2 is not optimal.  Would love an intuitive explanation!

Comment: @KevinWang - pls see if my answer below constitutes an intuitive explanation.  Robert - I would also really appreciate if you would read it and provide any comments / suggestions / corrections. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an intuitive, non-rigorous, *calculus-free* :) explanation for what is going on.  **Much credit goes to Robert Israel** whose excellent answer provided formulas for me to simulate, which inspired the claims & subsequent arguments below.

Following his notation, let $x$ be your pick of location, $y$ be the referee's location, and $f(x) $ be your win prob.

This answer attempts to intuitively argue for the following:

> Claim 1: In the large $n$ limit, $f(\frac12) = {1\over n+1}$.
>
> Claim 2: In the large $n$ limit, the optimal occurs at $x = {c\over n}$ (and by symmetry $x= 1 - {c \over n}$) for some small constant $c \approx \frac32$.  (In fact, my simulations show the max occurring at exactly $c=2$.)

Imagine this game is not played on the $[0,1]$ interval but rather on a circle.  Then clearly, your choice doesn't matter - you might as well pick $0$ - and since there are $n$ other players, your win prob is ${1 \over n+1}$ by symmetry (among players).

The key idea is this: When the game is played on the interval, and you get to pick $x$, this is equivalent to playing on the circle (and you picking location $0$) and then you get to *cut open the circle / draw a divider* at a distance $x$ from your location.

So $x$ affects your win prob to exactly the extent that the cut (divider) affects your win prob.  Well, you start with a win prob of ${1 \over n+1}$ and the cut only affects your win prob in precisely these two scenarios:

- **Scenario A: Turning a loss (in the circle game) into a win (in the interval game):** In the circle game, starting from your position $0$ and looking in one direction, the immediately next few points are: $0, y, x, z$ where $z$ is some other player and $|0-y| > |y -z|$.  I.e. without the cut $x$, you would have lost the circle game, but with the cut $x$, that cuts off the original winner $z$ and you are the new winner in the interval game.
- **Scenario B: Turning a win (in the circle game) into a loss (in the interval game):** In the circle game, starting from your position $0$ and looking in one direction, the immediately next few points are: $0, x, y, z$ where $|0-y| < |y-z|$.  I.e. without the cut $x$, you would have won the circle game, but with the cut $x$, that cuts you off and $z$ becomes the new winner.

In other words, we have:

$$f(x) = {1 \over n+1} + Prob(A) - Prob(B)$$

**(Rigorous?) Proof of Claim 1:** Scenario A requires that only the referee was between your $0$ and $x$, and scenario B requires that *nobody* was between your $0$ and $x$.  In the large $n$ limit, for $x=\frac12$, each event is exponentially unlikely.  Therefore $f(\frac12) = {1 \over n+1}$, same value as in the circle game.  In short, cut $x=\frac12$ is so far away in the large $n$ limit that it doesn't matter (so the two games are equivalent).  $\square$

**Non-rigorous argument for Claim 2:**

In both scenarios A and B, before the cut the ordering was $0, y, z$.  (If $y$ was not next to you in the circle game, you will lose both the circle game and the interval game no matter where you cut.)  Obviously, you want to place the cut between $y$ and $z$, i.e. on the other side of $y$ away from you.  Cutting too close and the cut might be on your side of $y$ (cutting you off), while cutting too far and it might not cut off $z$ at all.

The hand-waving comes from an intuitive guess at "aiming" the cut between $y$ and $z$.

In the circle, there will be $n+2$ points - one from the referee, one from you, and $n$ from the other players.  So the average length of any interval is ${1 \over n+2}$.  In particular, even when conditioned on $y$ being next to you, and $z$ being the other neighbor of $y$, we have $E[|0-y|] = E[|y-z|] = {1 \over n+2}$, because the conditioning only affects relative ordering / who's neighbor to whom.  From this alone, I would have guessed that a good strategy is to cut at $x = \frac32 {1 \over n+2}\approx {c \over n}$ where $c = \frac32$, i.e. one-and-a-half expected interval lengths away.  $\square$

**Further thoughts:** Based on my simulations, for large $n$ the optimal happens at $x = {c \over n}$ where $c=2$.  In retrospect, this bias (over $c = \frac32$) can probably be explained thus:

- In scenario A, you were on the longer / losing side of $y$, i.e. $E[|0-y|] \gtrapprox {1 \over n+2}$, so it makes sense to cut slightly further away than $c=\frac32$, just to overcome your slightly longer distance to $y$.
- In scenario B, you were on the shorter / winning side of $y$, i.e. $E[|0-y|] \lessapprox {1 \over n+2}$, so it makes sense to cut further away than $c=\frac32$, just to be extra safe that you don't accidentally cut yourself off from an already-winning position.

Comment: $+1$, very nice approach! Could you check the asymptotic winning probability in my answer against your simulations?

Answer (score 2):

Building on the very nice solution by antkam, we can calculate the asymptotics for the optimal choice and the corresponding winning probability.

So let $x$, $y$, $z$ be as defined in antkam’s answer. For large $n$, we can approximate the other players’ guesses as a Poisson process with density $n$. (The total number of guesses is fixed, but the resulting correlation between guesses appearing at different locations can be neglected as $n\to\infty$, since a guess at one location only reduces the density remaining for another location by a fraction $\frac1n$.) To simplify the calculations, I’ll do them for density $1$ and then rescale.

So we choose $0$ on the circle and then cut at $x$. The basic winning probability is $\frac1{n+1}\sim\frac1n$, and we need to calculate two corrections to this, dependent on $x$.

The case where we gain due to the cut is the one where $0\lt y\lt x\lt z$ with $y\gt z-y$. The probability for this to occur, conditional on $y$ being the first of the $n+1$ values, is

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{\frac x2}^xf_Y(y)\left(F_{Z-Y}(y)-F_{Z-Y}(x-y)\right)\mathrm dy
&=&
\int_{\frac x2}^x\mathrm e^{-y}\left(\mathrm e^{-(x-y)}-\mathrm e^{-y}\right)\mathrm dy
\\
&=&
\int_{\frac x2}^x\left(\mathrm e^{-x}-\mathrm e^{-2y}\right)\mathrm dy
\\
&=&\frac x2\mathrm e^{-x}+\frac12\left(\mathrm e^{-2x}-\mathrm e^{-x}\right)\;.
\end{eqnarray}

The case where we lose due to the cut is the one where $0\lt x\lt y\lt z$ with $y\lt z-y$. The probability for this to occur, conditional on $y$ being the first of the $n+1$ values, is

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_x^\infty\mathrm f_Y(y)\left(F_{Z-Y}(\infty)-F_{Z-Y}(y)\right)\mathrm dy
&=&
\int_x^\infty\mathrm e^{-y}\mathrm e^{-y}\mathrm dy
\\
&=&
\int_x^\infty\mathrm e^{-2y}\mathrm dy
\\
&=&
\frac12\mathrm e^{-2x}\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Subtracting the second result from the first yields

$$
\frac x2\mathrm e^{-x}-\frac12\mathrm e^{-x}\;,
$$

and setting the derivative to $0$ yields the optimum at $x=2$. This needs to be rescaled by the density $n$, so the optimum asymptotically occurs at $\frac2n$, in agreement with antkam’s findings. The difference in the winning probability also has to be multiplied by $\frac1{n+1}\sim\frac1n$, the probability for $y$ to be the first of the $n+1$ values. So the optimal winning probability is asymptotically

$$
\left(1+\frac{\mathrm e^{-2}}2\right)\frac1n\approx\frac{1.068}n\;.
$$

Comment: (1) My sim is at work, but YES I do remember staring at $1.06***$ and wondering what the heck is going on! Will confirm on Monday. (2) My so-called "simulation" is in fact "simulating" Robert's formula for $f(x)$! I.e. evaluating $f$ against a dense array of $x$ values to find max & argmax, something you can easily do too. (3) Basic Q: Why can we approximate with Poisson? There are exactly $n+1$ other points, so this is Poisson conditioned on there being $n+1$ "successes" or "arrivals", which makes it non-Poisson. Why is the Poisson approximation valid?

Comment: (4) I also didn't understand either integral :( can you further explain?  E.g. in the first one $e^{-y}$ in the interval $(x/2, x)$ obviously describe position of $y$, but how does $e^{-(x-y)} - e^{-y}$ describe what needs to happen with $z$ i.e. $x < z < 2y$?  Similar question for the 2nd integral also...  (5) But regardless of my questions, THANK YOU for finding a way to explain my sim results!  :)

Comment: Just re-did my so-called "sim" (see above) in an online python environment.  At $n=10^5$ the win prob is $\approx 1.0677/n$.  Bigger $n$ values died on me.  You probably have access to much better computing resources for this < 20-line simulation.  :)

Comment: @antkam: I made some changes to the answer trying to address your questions. I don't prove rigorously that the process asymptotically becomes a Poisson point process (in fact I wouldn't know what exactly to prove for that and how to prove it), but it seems clear to me that the correlations caused by the fixed number of guesses become negligible with $n\to\infty$ because we're only interested in two events and they only deplete the available density by a fraction $\frac2n$. As regards your result $1.0677/n$: Agreement to five digits is good enough for me :-)